# HOW TO ADD MUTIL WEB PART ON A PAGE ,DATA DIFFERENCE BUT DATA GET FROM GENERAL A LIST APP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, list, web-part, content-query-web-part

[image]

[image]r.com/Zseo0.png

I want add mutil app part into a page ,but the app part get data from 1 list app.
Please give me solution to do it?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple views(different filter condition) for your list and then display different view for list in same page.

[image]